# Reloading a Flickr request from author

Tags: jquery, flickr

I have my flickr gallery coded, but I want to be able to click on the Author's name and the page will reload just with the images from that author.

Here is my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Outbrain Test Gallery</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#flkr').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.tiles',
    isResizable: true,
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<ul />').prependTo('#flkr');
  $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
      var squares = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_q.jpg');
      if(i <= 20){
        $('<img/>').attr({
          alt: item.title, 
          src: squares, 
          height: '150', 
          width: '150'
        }).appendTo('#flkr ul').wrap('<li class="tiles"><a href="' + item.link + '"></a><p class="title">' + item.title + '</p><p class="author"><strong>By:</strong> ' + item.author + '</p><p class="date"><strong>Uploaded: </strong>' + item.published + '</p></li>');
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <ul id="flkr"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the way you have it now is working for you, the essence is then the same, you just have to change your `$.getJSON` url to match that of the one for the author.. and passing the URL to `getJSON` is the same as passing any other variable around.

The only thing you need to come up with is a means of obtaining the Authors URL for the next gallery you want to show. I would also `$.empty()` the `ul` your are filling initially before appending to it again.

Now as to how you get the next persons URL thats up to you. Im sure theres enough similarities in the URL you would be using that you can hardcode it in and use an ID number or member name, not sure how flickr handles its URLs for the API off hand, but in general its all the same. Just got to use the right API, for public member specific feeds, the rest should be fairly straight foward. In all, you are heading in the right direction.

Comment: All of the url's and authors are generated on the fly, as it is pulling in the post recent images from Flickr so there can't be any hard coding. 

The way I see it is to some how grab the 'item-author' value and then reload the page with the author ID in place in the getJSON url.. But I have no idea to do that, I am kinda new to Jquery